# Задачка по java

Tags: циклы, java

Помогите разобраться, почему в цикле for в первой итерации не срабатывает  String str = in.nextLine()?

```
import java.util.*;

public class ClassInOut {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println (">Number of rows:");    
        int strNum = in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<strNum; i++){
            System.out.println ("String "+i+" :");
            String str = in.nextLine();     
            arr.add(str);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
            System.out.println ("Your String: "+i+" "+arr.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int strNum = in.nextInt();   

зачем?

Comment: Что значит "не срабатывает"? Строка выполняется, код перепрыгивает через неё? Или выполняется, но в str не то значение, которое вы ожидали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, проблема вот в чём.

После кода

```
System.out.println (">Number of rows:");    
int strNum = in.nextInt();
```

пользователь набрал на клавиатуре число и enter. `in.nextInt()` считало только число, теперь во входном потоке enter, который ждёт, чтобы его считали.

Далее, следующий вызов

```
in.nextLine()
```

считывает всё до enter'а -- то есть в вашем случае пустую строку. Логично?

Мне кажется, стоит вместо

```
int strNum = in.nextInt();
```

использовать

```
int strNum = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Или возможно надо будет удалить перевод строки из результата `in.nextLine()` перед `parseInt`, проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо, с parseInt() все отлично сработало! Теперь я знаю как работает nextLine() )))))

Comment: @Митька: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(int i=0; i<strNum; i++){
            String str = "String "+i+" :";  
            System.out.println ("String "+i+" :");
            arr.add(str);
        }
```

Так всё будет работать, а если использовать "String str = in.nextLine();", то он будет ждать от вас ввода в консоль, но этого вы не делаете и поэтому он не срабатывает.Объяснение понятно? =)

Comment: ваш код вообще ничего не читает из консоли, думаете, не надо?

Comment: думаю)Так как в заданной задачке, таким кодом вполне решается задача!)