# Не перемешивается массив

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, коллекции, случайные-числа

Нужно перемешать в произвольном порядке элементы массива, введенные с клавиатуры. Однако, вместо перемешивания элементов, происходит перемешивание запятых.

Как это исправить?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Количество элементов массива: ");
        int size = scan.nextInt();

        String[] str = new String[size];

        System.out.println("Введите элементы массива: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            str[i] =  scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Введенные элементы массива:");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            System.out.println(" " + str[i]);
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        List<String> strL = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
        Collections.shuffle(strL, rand);
        System.out.println("Было: " + Arrays.toString(str));
        System.out.println("Стало: " + strL);
    }
}
```

Comment: о каких запятых идет речь? можете показать вывод программы и указать как хотите чтобы было? вы можете это сделать нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/860473/edit)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Задачка по java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170419/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 1):

Всё у вас работает, только проблема в том, что вы читаете `size - 1` строк, вернее вы читаете `size`, но одна у вас получается пустая.

Почему?

Потому что, у вас допустим есть ввод:

> 4
>
> Вась
>
> Федь
>
> Михаил
>
> Джонни

Как в этом случае будет работать ваш код:

```
int size = scan.nextInt(); //Считается 4, и только 4
```

Далее у вас цикл должен считать 4 строки:

1 строка будет пустой, потому что после 4 идет перевод строки, который посредством `nextInt()` не считался, вот на первой итерации он и считается.
Во второй строке будет `Вась`, в третьей `Федь`, в четвертой `Михаил`.
Джонни остаётся за бортом.

Самый простой способ избежать этого, это сделать так:

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо:

```
    int size = scan.nextInt();
```

Используйте:

```
    int size = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
```

Тогда вывод будет корректный:
Введенные элементы массива:
 1
 2
 3
Было: [1, 2, 3]
Стало: [2, 1, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно использую конструкцию

```
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            size = scan.nextInt();
        }
        scan.nextLine();
```

Тогда не нужно отлавливать NFE при парсинге, если вдруг прилетит не целое число.